# Getting designated id in tables in MYSQL UPDATE

Tags: php, sql

The problem here is I can't get a designated "id" when I tried to update a row table.

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn-input'])){
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $name = $_POST['farmername'];
 $numofchicks = $_POST['numofchicks'];
 $price = $_POST['price'];
 $weight = $_POST['weight'];
 $get_id = $_GET['get_id'];

  //Outgoing
 mysqli_query($dbconn, "INSERT INTO chickens_out(username, farmername, numofchicks, price, weight) VALUES('{$username}','{$name}', '{$numofchicks}', '{$price}', '{$weight}')");
 mysqli_query($dbconn, "UPDATE chickens_out SET price = price * $weight * $numofchicks WHERE id = '$get_id'"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why all have $_POST and it has $get_id = $_GET['get_id'];.

Should it be :

```
$get_id = $_POST['get_id'];
```